# Why do random access iterator's arithmetic operators accept / return int and not size_t?

Tags: c++, iterator

Since most operations on `std::vector` require / return `size_t` - that's the type I use for indexing. But now I've enabled all compiler warnings to fix some signed / unsigned conversion issues that I know I have, and this message surprised me:

> warning C4365: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to '__w64 int', signed/unsigned mismatch

It was generated by this code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
size_t idx = 0;
v.insert(v.begin() + idx + 1, 0);
```

I've got a lot of other similar messages suggesting that iterator's arithmetic operators accept and return `int`. Why not `size_t`? Fixing all these messages is a pain, and doesn't make my code prettier!

Comment: What do you mean by doing this `v.insert(v.begin() + idx + 1);` ?

Comment: Is `__w64 int` not `signed long long`, a.k.a. `std::ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: @alexolut: of course, I've forgotten the second argument there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've got a lot of other similar messages suggesting that iterator's arithmetic operators accept and return `int`.

Not necessarily `int`. It's the (signed) `difference_type` defined by the iterator type's `iterator_traits`. For most iterator types, this defaults to `ptrdiff_t`.

> Why not `size_t`?

Because arithmetic needs to work correctly with signed values; one would expect `it + (-1)` to be equivalent to `it - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It allows for things like `it += index;` where `index` can be both positive or negative (according to some logic).

Comparing with the following:

```
if (some_condition)
    it += index;
else
    it -= index;
```

Which would be needed if we could only pass unsigned values.