# Why don't standard random access iterators implement arithmetic for size_t?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is pretty much a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22559499/991425). The main problem is that this example

```
std::vector<int> v;
const size_t offset = 0;
v.insert(v.begin() + offset, 0);
```

gives the warning (when compiling with `-Wsign-conversion`):

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'const size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long') to 'const difference_type' (aka 'const long') [-Wsign-conversion]
```

I completely understand that there must be arithmetic for `difference_type`, however what I don't understand and what is also not answered in the linked question, is why there is no additional `operator+` for `size_t`.

My rather hackish solution to get rid of those warning is to implement it myself:

```
template<class IteratorType, 
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::difference_type, long>::value
        && std::is_class<IteratorType>::value
    , bool>::type = true>
IteratorType operator+(const IteratorType& _iterator, const size_t _add) {
    return _iterator + typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::difference_type(_add);
}
```

I haven't experienced any trouble so far. So I'd like to know the rational of why the standard does not provide this operator.

Comment: This compiles without warning on g++ 5.3 and clang 3.8, even with `-Wall`.

Comment: @Holt I did turn on `-Wsign-conversion` because I think it provides useful warnings in other circumstances.

Comment: Even with `-Wsign-conversion`, g++ and clang are quite happy.

Comment: For me the question is, why you do use size_t and not <iterator>::difference_type to declare your offset. Semantically an offset is a difference and for type safety and code readability it should be declared as such. size_t does in my opinion not express a specific semantic meaning and is confusing depending on the context where it is used.

Comment: @Holt Strange, for me it does. Using `clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -Wsign-conversion` on Fedora 24.

Comment: The other answer says: _"Because arithmetic needs to work correctly with signed values; one would expect it + (-1) to be equivalent to it - 1."_ Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: @black No it is actually not, because it does not explain why there is no additional `operator+` for unsigned values.

Comment: @black That doesn't explain why it can't also support unsigned arithmetic. It obviously needs to support signed arithmetic, but why not both? Personally, I think like Frank's comment, and I simply think that should be the answer to the question

Comment: @FrankSchmid The actual applications are of course more complicated than this minimal example (in which I would agree with you). And in those (imo) i does make much more sense to use `size_t`. Also I find  `v.begin() + offset` for a signed `offset` much more error prone than for an unsigned `offset`.

Comment: @KABoissonneault What would be the point of `std::advance` then?

Comment: You want to change the language because a compiler warns? That seems backwards. The code works, ask your compiler to stop warning... Btw, with the semantics of signed/unsigned, using an unsigned type (size_t) so much was a mistake in the standard.

Comment: Moreover there is the rather abstract point of view (correct me if I am wrong): The maximal value of `size_t` is basically defined by the standard to be maximal number of entries a standard container can have. So for a container actually using this limit it is impossible to address the second halve of the entries using `v.begin() + offset` with an unsigned `offset`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse See my last comment, I would kind of consider it a bug of the standard not only a failed compiler warning. I would however completely agree with you that using an unsigned `size_t` probably wasn't a wise choice.

Comment: @Haatschii Gcc doesn't support using half (or more) of the address space for a single object anyway. The maximum of size_t is only an upper bound.

Comment: @black The main point of `std::advance` is that i works for non-random access containers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Okey, but that is `GCC` not the standard, or does the standard also introduce that limit?

Answer (score 1):

Requiring there to be an `operator+` taking `size_t` in addition to the one that takes the signed type `difference_type` (which will often be `ptrdiff_t`, but doesn't necessarily need to be) would create more problems than it solves.

On your system, `size_t` is `unsigned long`. That's not guaranteed in general, but I'll assume it's the case for the rest of this answer.

Consider the following function with a single overload:

```
void f(long);
```

You can call `f` with an argument of any arithmetic type, any class type that has a conversion function to `long`, or any class type that has a conversion function template yielding an arbitrary arithmetic type (it will be instantiated such that it yields `long`).

Now consider what happens when a second overload is introduced:

```
void f(long);
void f(unsigned long);
```

`f` can no longer be called with an argument of type `int` or `unsigned int`; the overload resolution is ambiguous. In fact, it can no longer be called with arguments of any integer type other than `long` or `unsigned long`, or any floating-point type. If a class type has conversion functions to both `long` and `unsigned long` (or a template that can be instantiated to yield either) then the overload resolution will be ambiguous when a value of that class is passed to `f`, as well.

The author could provide an additional set of overloads in order to accept any arithmetic type, namely overloads taking `int`, `unsigned int`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, `double`, and `long double` (other arithmetic types will be promoted to one of these). They could say they don't really care about the case of class type, or they could write some kind of template, which imposes further burdens on them...

```
template <class T>
auto f(const T&) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_convertible_v<const T&, long>>;
```

In C++98, this would have been painful; `std::is_convertible` didn't exist, and they'd have to implement their own, which is possible but not trivial.

So there would need to be a huge amount of work put into this and the only benefit would be preventing a compiler warning. It's not worth the committee's time, it's not worth standard library implementors' time now (and definitely was not in C++98), and it's not worth the time of all other library implementors who would need to conform to the iterator requirements.