# Avoiding C4365 when mixing index and pointer arithmetic without casting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I have a code base where templates look up a value in one vector and then use the calculated index to get a value at a certain position.

Here is a bit of source made for visual studio to give a rough idea:

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable: 4514)
#pragma warning(disable: 4710) 
#pragma warning(disable: 4189)
#include <vector>

int main(int, char *[])
{
    //contrived example, never mind the non C4365 issues in this code
    //I am aware that this makes not a lot of sense runtime wise
    //This question is about a compiler warning
    int target;
    std::vector<char> first;
    std::vector<long> second;

    auto it = std::find(first.begin(), first.end(), target);
    //Warning C4365 '...': conversion from '...' to '...', signed/unsigned mismatch
    std::size_t pos = it - first.begin(); //from int to std::size_t
    long result = second.at(pos);

    return 0;
}
```

I am specifically interested in warning C4365.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173683.aspx) has an entry and there is another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559499/why-do-random-access-iterators-arithmetic-operators-accept-return-int-and-not) question related to this one.

I understand that this `std::size_t pos = static_cast<size_t>(it - first.begin());` removes the warning.

My question is if the above lookup and get value can be written so that a cast is not needed to avoid the warning.

EDIT: I did not mention that this warning is on warning level 4 and off by default.

Comment: `auto pos = it - first.begin();`?

Comment: @NathanOliver In this example the type would then be an int and that would move the warning to the next line where an unsigned is needed.

Comment: It does?  It doesn't on my machine.

Comment: @NathanOliver Interesting. Are you sure you turned /Wall on?

Comment: There we go.  I forgot to bump up the warning level.  I was on /W3.

Comment: I think the best you can do is abstract the cast away with a custom `distance` function that returns a unsigned type.

Comment: This sort of warning is annoying, as it's literally impossible for the result of subtraction to be out of range for size_t . I'd prefer to disable the warning than to mangle code which is correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below will generate no warning, as you'll add a `int` to an iterator, which is valid.

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
    //contrived example, never mind the non C4365 issues in this code
    //I am aware that this makes not a lot of sense runtime wise
    //This question is about a compiler warning
    int target;
    std::vector<char> first;
    std::vector<long> second;

    auto it = std::find(first.begin(), first.end(), target);
    auto it2 = second.begin() + ( it - first.begin() );
    long result = *it2;

    return 0;
}
```